# Excel SQL query slow with IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerquery

I am looking for a more efficient method of designing this query.
It is referencing 80 named cells in Excel and using an IN operator to compare the named cells.
I think the problem is with the IN operator, but I don't know of anyother way to reference the named cells in Excel.

```
SELECT distinct
                  dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.PRODORDER as 'OP', dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.QTYREQ, dbo.PRODORDER.BOMNO as 'CODIGO', dbo.ESPECIFICPART.DESCRIPT as 'DESCRIPCION', dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.ORDERDATE as 'FECHA OP', 
                  dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.DATEREQ as 'FECHA REQ', dbo.PRODORDER.MULTIPLOS, dbo.SALESMASTER.AutMaquina as 'VoBo', MAX(dbo.ProdOrderProcesos.Numero) AS 'PROCESOS', dbo.ESPECIFICPART.impresion AS 'IMPRESION'


FROM        dbo.SALES INNER JOIN
              dbo.PRODORDER INNER JOIN
              dbo.PRODORDERMASTER ON dbo.PRODORDER.PRODORDER = dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.PRODORDER INNER JOIN
              dbo.ProdOrderProcesos ON dbo.PRODORDER.PRODORDER = dbo.ProdOrderProcesos.ProdOrder ON dbo.SALES.IDDET_SALE = dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.IDDETALLE INNER JOIN
              dbo.SALESMASTER ON dbo.SALES.IDPEDIDO = dbo.SALESMASTER.IDPEDIDO INNER JOIN
              dbo.ESPECIFICPART ON dbo.PRODORDER.BOMNO = dbo.ESPECIFICPART.PARTNO

WHERE       (dbo.ProdOrderProcesos.Division = 'CAPLE') AND (dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.TipoEspecific <> 'Displays') AND 
            (dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.TipoEspecific <> 'Digital') AND (dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.FINISHED = 'False') AND (dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.CANCEL = 'False')
            AND 
            dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.PRODORDER IN ("& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_01")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_02"))
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_03")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_04")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_05")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_06")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_07")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_08")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_09")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_10")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_11")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_12")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_13")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_14")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_15")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_16")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_17")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_18")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_19")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_20")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_21")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_22")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_23")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_24")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_25")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_26"))
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_27")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_28")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_29")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_30")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_31")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_32")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_33")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_34")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_35")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_36")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_37")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_38")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_39")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_40")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_41")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_42")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_43")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_44")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_45")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_46")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_47")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_48")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_49")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_50")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_51")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_52")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_53")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_54")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_55")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_56")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_57")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_58")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_59")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_60")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_61")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_62")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_63")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_64")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_65")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_66")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_67")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_68")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_69")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_70")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_71")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_72")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_73")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_74")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_75")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_76")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_77")) 
              & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_78")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_79")) & ", "& Number.ToText(GetValue("OP_80"))
              &   ")

            GROUP BY dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.PRODORDER, dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.QTYREQ, dbo.PRODORDER.BOMNO, dbo.ESPECIFICPART.DESCRIPT, dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.ORDERDATE, dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.DATEREQ, 
              dbo.PRODORDER.MULTIPLOS, dbo.SALESMASTER.AutMaquina, dbo.ESPECIFICPART.impresion

            ORDER BY dbo.PRODORDERMASTER.PRODORDER ASC
```

If I only pass information to 60 of the named cells the query takes about 5 minutes, 70 cells about 10 minutes, and 80 cells time out.

Any ideas of making the more efficient please.

Comment: Did you try inserting those Number.ToText() into a table and join (without converting to text). This more looks like an SQL server query, put those values in a temp table and join.

Comment: Maybe you can try to split it in two steps. First, get your values from excel into #temp table and then join on that #temp table to filter out results. Maybe even create index on #temp table between the two steps.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT when GROUP BY is a bit eyebrows raising.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I will try to put these cells into a table and see if that helps. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: SQL server has to execute each function in your `IN` clause for each row, that's the reason why your query is slow.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I made a dynamic WHERE condition from a table with Power Query and I could run 100 references in less than a minute! Thanks